# 'iDocumentStore' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: lit-element

I have an interface:

```
export interface iDocumentStore {
    hasSpaceInfo: boolean;
    docId: string;
}
```

I get the following error when trying to do

```
 @property({ type: iDocumentStore })
```

Is there a way to specify a type interface for a property?

I'm create a web component using lit element.

Answer (score 1):

The [`type` option for properties](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#property-options) is a JavaScript type that Lit uses to convert a string attribute into a property and the property value into a string attribute at runtime. It is not not the same as TypeScript's type checking. You'll want to specify the TypeScript type as usual on the property and if the value will convert to/from JSON you can specify `Object` as the type for Lit to convert at runtime.

```
@property({ type: Object })
doc?: iDocumentStore;
```

[Example](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG48aGVhZD5cbiAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPVwibW9kdWxlXCIgc3JjPVwiLi9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmcuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8c2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nIGRvYz0ne1wiZG9jSWRcIjpcIjEyM1wifSc-PC9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmc-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)